# Click a tab of tabbarController programmatically

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have 2 tab buttons with Nib files....

On pressing a button on tab1, I want it want to show tab 2's view (not click on tabbar button2).  I mean, I want to click second tabbar button programmatically.

How can I do this, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a function with this in it:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

So eg:

```
- (void)selectNextTabBarView:(id)selector {
  [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

and then on your button you need:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectNextTabBarView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```