# Change current screen in TabBar Application on IOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've created a tabbar application using the template in Xcode, and have setup a working tab bar application. I want to know how I can change the view currently on the screen using a UIButton, so the result is the same as if the user just clicked one of the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is question was also asked by me and got good answer

look at

[Click a tab of tabbarController programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880922/click-a-tab-of-tabbarcontroller-by-programming)

hope it will help....