# TabBar: first to be shown ViewController after application launch

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, launch

I have a TabBar with 3 ViewControllers. By default the first one is selected after the app starts. How can I make the second one is selected by default, of course without changing the order of the Tabs in the Bar.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many exact same questions. Please research more before posting duplicate questions. e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880922/click-a-tab-of-tabbarcontroller-by-programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use [controller setSelectedIndex:] ?

In your case it is:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]
```

Comment: Outch... seems like I've overlooked that. Thanks!!